# If $f(x)=x^3+x+1$ , then find $(f^{-1})'(a)$ when $a=1$ .

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=x^3+x+1$ , then find $(f^{-1})'(a)$ when $a=1$ .

I have taken $f(x)=y$ and tried to solve the problem but i could not arrive at the solution. So, please provide me with the correct solution and the inverse of the function $f(x)$.

NOTE: $(f^{-1})'(x)$ = $1/f'(f^{-1}(x))$.

Comment: Hint: You don't need to find $f^{-1}$. It suffices to find $f^{-1}(1)$, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

First, $f'(x) = 3x^2 + 1 > 0$ for all real $x$, so $f$ is increasing, hence, one-to-one.

By inspection, you can see that $f(0) = 1$, so $f^{-1}(1) = 0$.  Therefore,
$$
(f^{-1})'(1) = \frac{1}{f'(0)} = \frac{1}{1} = 1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

To find $f^{-1}(1)$ you must solve
$$
1=x^3+x+1.
$$
This is equivalent to 
$$
0=x^3+x.
$$
You can then use the formula in your note.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chain rule for this one. If $y = x^3+x+1$ then, as you know,
$$\frac{\operatorname{d}\!y}{\operatorname{d}\!x} = 3x^2+1$$
The chain rule tells us that
$$\frac{\operatorname{d}\!x}{\operatorname{d}\!y} = \frac{1}{3x^2+1}$$
Notice that this expression is well-defines since $3x^2+1 \ge 1$ for all real $x$.

When $y=1$ you have $x^3+x+1=1$ and so $x(x^2+1)=0$. This is true for real values of $x$ if, and only if, $x=0$. Hence:

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}\!x}{\operatorname{d}\!y} = \frac{1}{0+1}=1$$